# what is java .classdata file extension

Tags: java, jar, compilation

I opened a jar file with JD-GUI and found the file with .classdata extension, can anyone help me to explain what is '.classdata' extension file here. How class files are compiled and added like this in jar's. [image]

Comment: this is obfuscation, done by opentelemetry.

Comment: How to do obfuscation on class files, do you know any tools or documentation? How obfuscated files it works in classpath?